# PuTTY not showing character | and _ correctly in pstree and tree command output

Tags: linux, putty, character-encoding

On Linux, `tree` and `pstree` commands show tree-like hierarchy of directories and processes respectively.

Their output usually includes the characters `|` and `_` which are used to draw the tree structure.

When I use PuTTY to ssh into my instances (Ubuntu 18.04 and Centos 7), the output 
show these characters as `â`.

If I use `cmd` to ssh into my instances and run the same command, the output is rendered correctly.

How do I fix this in PuTTY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your problem. It occurs with many character sets different than UTF-8, when the server uses UTF-8. Even if UTF-8 is not the right set in your particular case (but it probably is), this is the option you should change.

In PuTTY configuration the option is under Window→Translation, Remote character set.

[image: config window]